# iostat & steal time

Tags: bash, time, iostat

I am trying to catch some data from iostat output:

> ```
> # iostat  -m
>
> avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
>            9.92    0.00   14.17    0.01    0.00   75.90
>
> Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
> sda               6.08         0.00         0.04       2533     261072
> dm-0              1.12         0.00         0.00       1290      30622
> dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00          1          0
> dm-2              1.22         0.00         0.00          0      33735
> dm-3              7.22         0.00         0.03       1213     196713
> ```

How can I match the "0.00" value?
Numbers aren't separated by a tab or a constant number of spaces.
Also the value can be 3 digits 0.00 or 4 digits 45.00, etc.

Any idea how to match it using bash?

Comment: _which_ `0.00` value? The `%nice` number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using `awk`:

```
iostat | awk 'NR==3 { print $5 }'
```

`NR==3` will operate on the *third* line, and `$5` prints column *5*. Verify that the proper column is being selected by playing around with the number, i.e. using your output and `print $4` should yield *0.01*.